# How to find all digits before word with regex in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I am using Jenkins Pipeline and for writing Pipeline script we have to use Groovy. 
So, I would like to parse console output to find all digits before specific word
e.g. there are strings:

- 838123 someWord
- 8 someWord
- 12 someWord

And output should be: `838123`, or `8` or `12`.

I use regex: `.*(\\d+)\\ssomeWord.*` but it returns only latest digit, e.g. `3` in `838123`.

Comment: Can your strings contain `someWord` multiple times? What should happen to `838123 someWord 8 someWord`, also what should be output for `838123 8 someWord`? Also, what if `someWord` doesn't exist in the string, what do you want as the result (i.e. `838123 some`)?

Comment: Remove `.*`, the first `.*` makes `\d+` capture the single digit before the whitespaces and `someWord`. BTW, what is the code you are using? In Groovy, there are regex matching operators that require and that do not require a full string match.

Comment: removing .* should work: https://regex101.com/r/zLOkw6/1/

Comment: @Victor It will only work if OP uses the right regex matching operator.

Comment: No, string can contain only one 'someWord'. 
This is Groovy language which is used for writing script for Jenkins Pipeline Jobs

BTW, I am using this online tester https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to verify regex. It works exactly the same as regex in Jenkins Pipeline Groovy

Answer (score 3):

When you use your regex (see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/tyTEso/1)), the first `.*`, being a greedy subpattern due to the `*` (0 or more occurrences) quantifier, matches as many chars as it can (any 0+ chars other than line break chars) and then backtracks trying to accommodate some text for the subsequent subpatterns. `(\d+)` finds `3` in `838123` and since it meets the requirement of *1 or more digits*, calls it a day, then matches a whitespace and `someWord` -> the match is found.

As an option, you might use a lazy quantifier here, `.*?(\\d+)\\ssomeWord.*`, but there is a better way.

You may use the regex without `.*` at both ends, but make sure you are using it with `=~`, not with `==~` operator (the latter requires a full string match):

```
def s="838123 someWord\n8 someWord\n12 someWord"
def rx = /(\d+)\s*someWord/
def res = s =~ rx
(0..<res.count).each { println res[it][1] }
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/3MXa3Y).

Results:

```
838123
8
12
```